# Check Which File Is Newer

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to make a script that will prompt the user for two file names. verify the files names exist and are regular files. If both exist and are regular files display a message which file of the two files are older. If they're the same then just display either one.

Any help would be appericated

```
  #!/bin/bash
FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]
then
    echo "File $FILE does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, I recently commented on your last question related to a interactive bash script with a menu prompt. But next time I check to provide you an answer your question was removed. Could you recreate it, but more concisely? Do you managed to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for any number of files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(($# > 0)) || exit 1

files=("$@")

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || { echo "'$file' is not a regular file!"; exit 2; }
done

oldest=${files[0]}
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    [[ $file -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$file
done

echo "Oldest is: $oldest"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the -nt and -ot flags to compare two files by modification date. Info from the test manpage below (**man test**)

```
   FILE1 -nt FILE2
         FILE1 is newer (modification date) than FILE2
   FILE1 -ot FILE2
          FILE1 is older than FILE2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=$1
FILE2=$2

for f in "$FILE1" "$FILE2" ; do
    if [ ! -f "$f" ] ; then
        echo "File $f does not exist or is not a regular file"
        exit 1
    fi
done

if [ "$FILE1" -nt "$FILE2" ] ; then
    echo "$FILE1"
else
    echo "$FILE2"
fi
```